# Autoboxing in spring bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autoboxing

I am using spring 4.0.5 & Java 1.7.0-51. I create a spring bean of type Integer & set the value through it's constructor as follows in Applicationcontext.xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.beans"></context:component-scan>
    <bean id="user.min" class="java.lang.Integer"> <constructor-arg value="30" /></bean>
    <bean id="machine.min" class="java.lang.Integer"> <constructor-arg value="30" /></bean>
</beans>
```

I inject these beans to my class, where I already set some default values.

```
    @Component
    public class Token {

        @Autowired(required = false)
        @Qualifier("user.min")
        private Integer userMin = 480;
        @Autowired(required = false)
        @Qualifier("machine.min")
        private int machineMin = 480;

    public Integer getUserMin() {
        return userMin;
    }
    public void setUserMin(Integer userMin) {
        this.userMin = userMin;
    }
    public int getMachineMin() {
        return machineMin;
    }
    public void setMachineMin(int machineMin) {
        this.machineMin = machineMin;
    }
```

When I print these values, I get following values.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ApplicationContext context  = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Applicationcontext.xml");
    Token t = context.getBean(Token.class);

    System.out.println("User:"+t.getUserMin());
    System.out.println("Machine:"+t.getMachineMin());
}

Output:
User:30
Machine:480
```

[image]

The value to userMin (class Integer) is injected from bean, but machineMin (primitive type int) value is not injected.

The primitive type `'int'` is not Autoboxed to `Integer`. Is it a bug in Spring or the way I did the configuration is wrong? I am working it on Windows 7 (Eclipse Juno). Someone please help.

Comment: What does `getMachineMin` do? Is there anything else you aren't showing us? Why are you using `Integer` beans instead of `@Value` and properties?

Comment: I am not hiding anything from here. I've posted all the complete setup in my local machine. Actually this 'Integer' thing is an existing project setup & the trouble was identified recently. So I tested the issue by creating the local setup only with the piece of code that is suspected to cause the trouble. And fortunately that is replicated too. :( And for your @Value question, we are using some dynamic configurations to populate the bean value in xml file during deployment (the value varies between different environments, so it's been setup like this)

Comment: getMachineMin is nothing but a getter method.

Comment: This is the complete setup. There is nothing else apart from this in my project. I use Windows 7, eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Spring, with annotation configuration, annotates by type (first and then by name). It looks for a bean of whatever type the field or method (or constructor) parameter is. In your case, that is `int` and there is no bean of type `int` in the `ApplicationContext`. Since your injection target is not required, Spring does not throw an exception.

I wouldn't say this is a bug, there are workarounds, just not with `@Autowired`.